# Javascript submitting a form within a method

Tags: php, javascript, post

I have a method which prints out the order of a set of images. I need to submit this to a new php page.

I have a form which currently prints out the order to the same page.

```
<form action="mainpage.php" method="post">
<div style="clear:both;padding-bottom:10px">

    <input type="Button" style="width:100px" value="Show order" onclick="saveImageOrder()">

</div>
```

`Saveimageorder()` shows the image and it saves the order in a variable called orderString

```
function saveImageOrder()
{
    var orderString = "";
    var objects = document.getElementsByTagName('DIV');

    for(var no=0;no<objects.length;no++)
    {
        if(objects[no].className=='imageBox' || objects[no].className=='imageBoxHighlighted')
        {
             if(orderString.length>0) orderString = orderString + ',';
             orderString = orderString + objects[no].id;
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('debug').innerHTML = 'This is the new order of the images(IDs) : <br>' + orderString;    
}
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can submit the form with (note that this isn't tested):

```
document.formname.submit();
```

If you need to change the action (the page to submit to) first:

```
document.formname.action = 'some_other_url';
```

If you need to submit the form asynchronously you need to use a XMLHttpRequest or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

with plain POST (no ajax) you need to store the result of your process (image order id retrieval) in an form field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="imagesorder" value=""/>
```

in your function, you can set the value to this field after the orderString is populated:

```
document.getElementsByName('imagesorder')[0].value = orderString;
```

then submit the form, you can do this by replacing your

```
<input type="button" .../>
```

with

```
<input type="submit" .../>
```

on the server side you will then get the value in the post collection (I'm not php dev)

```
$_POST['imagesorder']
```

Comment: Note a typo on the last line.. It should be $_POST['imagesorder']